# Multilevel register/login system

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I want to create a multilevel register/login system with 2 types of users: admin and normal users.
I have read some articles and tutorials, but I still have some questions. I know that I need to have a table with the following columns: username, password and type (0 - normal user, 1 - admin) and when a user tries to login, he will be redirected to a certain page based on the type.

Now, the process of registration for a normal user is quite straightforward, but my question is, how do you register an admin user?

Do you add a admin user directly in the database using sql? Do you create a special PHP page for this?

Like I said, I have read some tutorials but I didn't found an answer to this question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Entirely your choice. That's the wonderful thing about programming.

Comment: I would say the best approach would be for you to manually set which users that should be admins on an admin page or in e.g. phpmyadmin

Comment: I wouldn't use a `type` column for your users.  You are severely limiting the scalability of complexity in the future.  We are suffering issues with people having up to 3 user accounts for this reason.  Go with a roles based solution, one user, many roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the kind of application / website you are going to code.

If you're planning on building an expanding, modular site, adding admins directly via SQL is not the right way. Then a separate page would be best, that only existing admins or operators (that would require more ranks, but in any bigger sytem, there are more than two ranks anyway) can access.

However, if you just want to test things out, adding those special accounts via SQL requires much less effort than coding a separate page only for this purpose.

Note that user / group privilege management is a critical security part, so make sure to check things on the server (--> input validating).

Added content : Depending on the size of the project and the scalability you want to achieve, you may consider separate tables for the privileges of users / groups, which could be included to your SQL statements using JOINs.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the developer.I recommend  you to  create a row in the database for assigning the user role and redirect the user to admin dashboard or user dashboard.. If it's for your personal need , you can create an admin dashboard and put it some where in the server and access it when you need to modify the website ...

Answer (score 0):

you can use my logic there

```
public function aksi_login(){
            $valid_user=$this->login_mod->check_credential();
            if ($valid_user==FALSE) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Wrong Username/Password');
                redirect('login');
            }else{
                $this->session->set_userdata('username',$valid_user->username); 
                $this->session->set_userdata('foto',$valid_user->foto);
                $this->session->set_userdata('id_jurusan',$valid_user->id_jurusan); 
                switch ($valid_user->id_jurusan) {
                    case 1: //admin
                            redirect('guru');
                            break;
                    case 2: //member
                            redirect(base_url());
                            break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
    }

    public function logout(){
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('login');
    }
```

you can use my logic model codeigniter for login

```
public function check_credential(){
        $email=set_value('email');
        $password=set_value('password');
        $hasil=$this->db->where('email',$email)
                        ->where('password',$password)
                        ->limit(1)
                        ->get('user');  

        if ($hasil->num_rows()>0) {
            return $hasil->row();
        }else{
            return array();
        }
    }
    function all($table){
        return $this->db->get($table);
    }
    public function input($data,$table){
        return $this->db->insert($table,$data);
    }
```